# oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle19c

Getting the above error but the offending column is not a number.  Somehow it is related to the cycle_code column which is a string.  My query is hacky since I dont have full control over building it so I have to append another condition at the end ( "!= 'ABC'").  If I remove that condition the query works.  I dont understand why im getting an invalid number error though?

```
select * from my_view WHERE ... CYCLE_CODE IN ( 'XYZ' ) AND CYCLE_CODE != 'ABC';
```

Comment: If `cycle_code` is really defined as a `varchar2`, then something in `my_view` is trying to do an implicit conversion and failing.

Comment: Is there a way to use literally *any* other added condition? The negative lookup will affect your ability to use indexes on that column and may hurt the performance of the query. Could you use something like "AND 1=1"?